# Android: Change actionbar style

Tags: android

I am currently trying to change the style of my action bar to accomplish the following:

- Changing the color of the action bar
- Changing the logo of the action bar
- Removing the activity name from the action bar

In order to do so, this is what I have tried:

`Manifest` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shoppinglist"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeWithoutActionBarTitle">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.shoppinglist.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:logo="@drawable/mylogo">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And in `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
</style>

    <style name="ActionBarWithoutTitle" parent="@style/ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo</item>
</style>

    <style name="AppThemeWithoutActionBarTitle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarWithoutTitle</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

However, when I tried this, everything worked except for replacing the app logo: instead of the new logo `@drawable/mylogo`, no logo appears at all. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close to the right answer. All you need is to modify one element in your `styles.xml` file to the following:

```
<style name="ActionBarWithoutTitle" parent="@style/ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
</style>
```

The addition of `showHome|` will allow for the logo you need to be present.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set in your `Activity` whether you want to use the launcher icon or the logo icon. So add this line to your `Activity` in `onCreate`:

```
setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Also your approach can be done programatically as well:

```
getActionBar().setTitle("");
getActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.my_logo);
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_background_drawable));
```

This would of course be a good solution, if you wanted to add different styles to different `Activities`, but would be a bit cumbersome, if you have more `Activities` and wanted the same style all over.

Comment: `setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);` requires me to add other methods. Also, I tried the programmatic approach, but they only changed everything after onCreate, so the few moments while the activity was loading, everything looked different.